# Sum one number to every element in a list (or array) in Python

Tags: python, list, sum

Here I go with my basic questions again, but please bear with me.

In Matlab, is fairly simple to add a number to elements in a list:

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1]
b = a + 1
```

`b` then is `[2,2,2,2,2]`

In python this doesn't seem to work, at least on a list.

Is there a simple fast way to add up a single number to the entire list.

Thanks

Answer (score 88, accepted):

if you want to operate with list of numbers it is better to use NumPy arrays:

```
import numpy
a = [1, 1, 1 ,1, 1]
ar = numpy.array(a)
print ar + 2
```

gives

```
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 32):

using List Comprehension:

```
>>> L = [1]*5
>>> [x+1 for x in L]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
>>>
```

which roughly translates to using a for loop:

```
>>> newL = []
>>> for x in L:
...     newL+=[x+1]
... 
>>> newL
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

or using map:

```
>>> map(lambda x:x+1, L)
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use map:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
b = 1
list(map(lambda x: x + b, a))
```

It gives:

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

try this. (I modified the example on the purpose of making it non trivial)

```
import operator
import numpy as np

n=10
a = list(range(n))
a1 = [1]*len(a)
an = np.array(a)
```

`operator.add` is almost more than two times faster

```
%timeit map(operator.add, a, a1)
```

than adding with numpy

```
%timeit an+1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want list comprehensions:

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1]
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append(i+1)
```