# "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list" What have I done wrong?

Tags: python

```
def ifWin2(el):
    el2, el3 = el[2],el[3]
    if el2 > el3:
        el2 = el2 + 3000
        el3 = el3 + 50
    elif el2 < el3:
        el2 = el2 + 50
        el3 = el3 + 3500
    else:
        el2 = el2 + 1000
        el3 = el3 + 1000
```

The above code gives me TypeError, saying it "can only concatenate list (not "int") to list" (which I do know). However, I'm sure that neither el2 nor el3 are multidimensional lists. Why might I be getting this error?

Comment: What does `el2` and `el3` look like?

Comment: Sure, neither `el2` nor `el3` are multidimensional lists—but `3000` is not a list at all. You're doing exactly what the error says you're doing. Either call `el2.append(3000)` if you want to mutate in-place, or `el2 = el2 + [3000]` if you want to copy.

Comment: Or just use `el2 += [3000]` @abarnert.

Comment: @ChristianDean Sure, but there's no really good reason to do that here, and I think it will just confuse him with the difference between what `+=` does for mutable vs. immutable types.

Answer (score 0):

```
el2 = el2 + 3000
```

That `el2` may be a single-dimensional list, but that `3000` isn't a list at all, it's just an `int`. Hence the error message:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not ”int“) to list”
```

If you want to concatenate the single-element list containing `3000`, that's spelled `[3000]`:

```
el2 = el2 + [3000]
```

However, unless you need to avoid mutating the original list for some reason, you probably want to just `append` to it:

```
el2.append(3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to add a constant to a list. In that case you should use a Numpy array:

[Sum one number to every element in a list (or array) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754571/sum-one-number-to-every-element-in-a-list-or-array-in-python#5754606)