# Faster for loops using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, loops

In my dataframe, I have to repeat the same function 300000 times, each time adding 1 to a variable `var`. The easy way for me to do this is by using a for loop

```
for var in range(0,300000): 
   function(var)
```

Is there a faster way to iterate this function? (I don't really know if is important in this case, but my function is doing its thing over a np.array)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

Comment: Have a look at this example. Assuming you are just adding 1 to a Numpy array. If the array is named data, you should just be able to do data = data + 1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754571/sum-one-number-to-every-element-in-a-list-or-array-in-python

Comment: the function in step n was executed on the result of the function in n-1?

Comment: It depends on what `function` is doing.  If it's something that can be [vectorized](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), or is already vectorized, then you can do `function(np.arange(300000))`.  But if not, then you gotta do a loop, although again depending on the function, a [list comprehension](https://leadsift.com/loop-map-list-comprehension/) might be faster.

Comment: @stevemo, don't suggest `np.vectorize`.  It will not run faster (read its disclaimer).

Comment: Your `function` only gets a scalar integer.  What's this `array` it's  "doing its thing over".  And where's the `dataframe` in the story.  Lots of vagueness in this question.  But the short answer is, if `function` is a python function that only works with one scalar at time, the you have to call for each of those 30000... times.  The trick to doing things faster in `pandas` and `numpy` is to write functions that use fast compiled methods that work with *whole* arrays and frames (not just with one integer at a time).