# How to create a second list in python, relative with first list

Tags: python

I have a question, how can we create a second list in python, which every content of this list is about 10 larger than first list. I can't solve it by loop(for).
For example:

```
l1[2] = 2 
 l2[2] = 12
```

or

```
 l1 = [0,1,2,3]
 l2 = [10,11,12,13]
```

Thank You

Comment: Just do `l2 = [v + 10 for v in l1]`.  It's called a list comprehension.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum one number to every element in a list (or array) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754571/sum-one-number-to-every-element-in-a-list-or-array-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try (This is a list comprehension, where it iterates over the first list and adds 10 to each item):

```
l2 = [x+10 for x in l1]
print(l2)
```

This is the short version of:

```
l2 = []
for i in l1:
    l2.append(i+10)
```